# How to print a distinct string in this pattern in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program in java which would give a pattern for an inputted string as follows

```
C O M P U T E R
O             E
M             T
P             U
U             P
T             M
E             O
R E T U P M O C
```

Here is my program code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class pandapattern
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word : ");
        String s=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        int l=s.length();
        for(int i=0;i<+l;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(i)+" ");
        }
        char[][] frwd = new char[l][1];
        char[][] bcwd = new char[l][1];
        for(int f=1;f<l;f++)
        {
            frwd[f][0]=s.charAt(f);
        }
        for(int b=l-2;b>=0;b--)
        {
            bcwd[b][0]=s.charAt(b);
        }
        for(int p=1;p<l;p++)
        {
            System.out.print("\n"+frwd[p][0]);
        }
        for(int p1=l-1;p1>=0;p1--)
        {
            System.out.print(bcwd[p1][0]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

I get this pattern:

```
C O M P U T E R
O
M
P
U
T
E
R  E T U P M O C
```

How would I get the whole pattern printed out?

Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Aside from your main question, `new char[l][1]` doesn't make sense. It is `ix1` array which is simply one dimensional `i` array (you just drop `[0]` from `[p][0]`).

Comment: In your next to last loop (`for(int p=1;p<l;p++)`), you should print characters of both the forward and backward Strings, separated by sufficient spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for this task you need one-dimension arrays `frwd` and `bcwr`

Secondly, you fill array `bcwd` in the same way as `frwd`.

Rewritten part of your method correctly for the task:

```
    int length = s.length();
    //printing first line
    for (int i = 0; i < +length; i++) {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    //filling arrays
    char[] frwd = new char[length];
    char[] bcwd = new char[length];
    for (int f = 1; f < length; f++) {
        frwd[f] = s.charAt(f);
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < length; b++) {
        bcwd[b] = s.charAt(length-1 - b);
    }

    for (int p = 1; p < length-1; p++) {
        System.out.print(frwd[p]);

        //filling spaces to line by length of input string
        for (int p3 = 1; p3 < frwd.length-1; p3++) {
            System.out.print(" " + " ");
        }

        System.out.print(" " + bcwd[p]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int p = 0; p <= length - 1; p++) {
        System.out.print(bcwd[p] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

And you can use just input string without extra char arrays. Just get characters from string (`s.charAt(i)`) in straight and backwar loops.

Answer (score 2):

You onle need ***one*** `char[]`  array, not more.
The trick is to take the problem *"row-by-row"*.

See below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter word for Panda Pattern: ");
        String word = scanner.nextLine();
        String wspace = " ";
        //convert user input from String to char[]
        char[] wordLetters = word.toCharArray();
        //define array's length, for ease of reference
        int length = wordLetters.length;

        //initially print the sentence in a horizontal line
        for (char wordLetter : wordLetters) {
            System.out.print(wordLetter + wspace);
        }
        //insert new line to start printing for the pattern
        System.out.print("\n");

        /*A for loop that will print the left-most letters vertically
         We start the loop from 1, because the first letter was already printed*/
        for(int i=1; i<length; i++){
            System.out.print(wordLetters[i]);
            /*now we have an inner loop that will print the spaces and the
             rest of the letters in reverse order*/
            for(int j=1; j<length; j++){
                //conditional for IF we are at final line
                if(i == length-1 && j != length-1)
                    System.out.print(wspace + wordLetters[i-j]);
                //conditional for printing right-most letters
                else if(j == length-1) {
                    System.out.print(wspace + wordLetters[j-i]+"\n");
                }
                //THIS WILL PRINT 2 WHITE-SPACES.
                else
                    System.out.print(wspace + wspace);
            }
        }
    }
```

> Why didn't I need a second array ?

Since this pattern requires only one word, then printing in reverse, means that there is still the **same amount of letters** to process, so any additional arrays would have the same length.

Ergo, we can omit creating new arrays altogether!

Why not manipulate the power that `for-loops` & `arrays` give us?

Comment: @JyotirmayKumarJha Added appropriate spaces, so that you can get the format you want